# Install applications without touching the smartphone

Tags: apps, internet

Is it possible to install application to windows phone without touching it. Just via internet from another computer. I can do it on adroid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can install apps over-the-air from the [Windows Phone Store on the web](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store).

[image: Install]

Just click the install button.